# Spring Boot JUnit Test - How to return response from Wiremock

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, wiremock

I have a problem about returning the response from the request through wiremock in JUnit test of Spring Boot. As I use Microservices, I have to use wiremock to call any method of another microservice.

I want to write a wiremock to get the token value from this process.

I tried to write the process but I cannot complete it. How can I do that?

```
@RegisterExtension
static WireMockExtension wireMockserver
        = WireMockExtension.newInstance()
        .options(WireMockConfiguration
                .wireMockConfig()
                .port(8080))
        .build();


wireMockserver.stubFor(get("/authenticate/login")
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
));
```

How can I get the response?

Here is the response shown below.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JWTResponse {
    private String token;
    private String type = "Bearer";
    private String refreshToken;
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private List<String> roles;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct wire mock to return a body in the response.

For example:

```
    JWTResponse expected = podamFactory.manufacturePojo(JWTResponse.class);
wm.stubFor(post(testUrl)
     .willReturn(ok()
     .withBody(mapper.writeValueAsString(expected))
     .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/hal+json")));
```

Where mapper is an instance of `ObjectMapper mapper;`

What we do here is to return the expected object when a post ist performed on the specific testUrl. As the object is transferred as json we need to use the mapper to transfer the object to a corresponding string representation.